# Schematic of an amplifier with bandpass filter and impedance matching

Tags: amplifier, filter, schematics, impedance-matching, mentor-pads

I am having trouble creating a block diagram in PADS Professional Designer. My [HMC414 amplifier](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/hmc414.pdf) has IN input, two OUT outputs, and additionally VCC, VPD1, VPD2 and GND pins (there is also NC [Not Connected] pin). My [DEA142450BT-3028A1 filter](https://product.tdk.com/info/en/documents/data_sheet/rf_bpf_dea142450bt-3028a1_en.pdf) has 3 GND pins, one Input Port and one Output Port. I made a block diagram of the amplifier with the output matching and the filter, it looks like this:

[image: link]

I know of course that I have to connect all GND pins to ground and the VCC port to +5 V. I've done impedance matching on the input (did I do it right?), I've connected my filter to the OUT1 port (does it look ok too?). I don't know what to do with the other ports, though. What should I plug into VPD1 and VPD2? And should I do the impedance matching on the output the same way as on the input of the amplifier, only connect it to the filter port "OUTPUT_PORT"?

Comment: @rfdave Thank you for comment. I edited my title form "block diagram" to schematic. Sorry but there is no page 11 on my data sheets (only 8 and 6). I would like to know if I have connected the amplifier properly with filter and matching at the input, and if connecting something to the other pins is necessary?

Answer (score 0):

So that's not a block diagram, that's a schematic.  Have you read the datasheet? There's a schematic on page 11 that should answer many of your questions. VPD1 and VPD2 are intended to allow you to power down the amplifier, what do you want to do?

I'd suggest some bypassing on Vcc, again the schematic on P11 should point you in the direction to go. You should also look carefully at how Vcc is connected, as you also need to connect Out_1 and Out_2 to Vcc

Comment: I edited my title form "block diagram" to schematic. Sorry but there is no page 11 on my data sheets (only 8 and 6). I would like to know if I have connected the amplifier properly with filter and matching at the input, and if connecting something to the other pins is necessary?

Comment: Sorry, misread the numbering. Look on the last page of the documentation link, should be a schematic there.

Comment: Thank you for help. I managed to create a schematic and it now looks like this: https://imgur.com/MiNwQuN   I hope it is good :)

Comment: Looks much better. Now you get to dive into the joys of transmission line design 